# Convert infinite stream of finite streams to an infinite stream - Reactive X

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactivex, reactive-streams

How in Reactive x (ideally with examples in RxJava or RxJs) can be achieved this ?

```
a |-a-------------------a-----------a-----------a----
s1 |-x-x-x-x-x-x -| (subscribe)
s2                       |-x-x-x-x-x-| (subscribe)
s2                                               |-x-x-x-x-x-| (subscribe)
...
sn
S |-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-------x-x-x-x-x-x-x-------------x-x-x-x-x-x- (subsribe)
```

`a` is an infinite stream of events which trigger finite stream `sn` of events each of which should be part of infinite stream `S` while being able to subscribe to each `sn` stream ( in order to do summation operations) but at the same time keeping stream `S` as infinite.

EDIT: To be more concrete I provide the implementation of what I am looking for in Kotlin.
Every 10 second an event is emitted which maps to shared finite stream of 4 events. The metastream is `flatMap`-ed into normal infinite stream. I make use of `doAfterNext` to additionally subscribe to each finite stream and print out results.

```
/** Creates a finite stream with events
 * $ch-1 - $ch-4
 */
fun createFinite(ch: Char): Observable<String> =
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .take(4)
                .map({ "$ch-$it" }).share()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var ch = 'A'

    Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).startWith(0)
            .map { createFinite(ch++) }
            .doAfterNext {
                it
                        .count()
                        .subscribe({ c -> println("I am done. Total event count is $c") })
            }
            .flatMap { it }
            .subscribe { println("Just received [$it] from the infinite stream ") }

    // Let main thread wait forever
    CountDownLatch(1).await()
}
```

However I am not sure if this is the 'pure RX' way.

Comment: This looks like `concatMap` but it's unclear from the question how you'd map each event onto a set of N inner sources.

Comment: Perhaps add an example of what you have tried so far, that will give us a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/173/576/Wat8.jpg - Me reading the title

Comment: @inf It's not ideal I know since I am just getting my feet wet with rx. You are welcome to edit it.

Comment: @dev-null It was a joke really, I have no clue what `rx` is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't make clear how you want to do the counting. If you are doing a total count, then there is no need to do the interior subscription:

```
AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong()
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).startWith(0)
        .map { createFinite(ch++) }
        .flatMap { it }
        .doOnNext( counter.incrementAndget() )
        .subscribe { println("Just received [$it] from the infinite stream ") }
```

On the other hand, if you need to provide a count for each intermediate observable, then you can move the counting inside the `flatMap()` and print out the count and reset it on completion:

```
AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong()
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).startWith(0)
        .map { createFinite(ch++) }
        .flatMap { it
                     .doOnNext( counter.incrementAndget()
                     .doOnCompleted( { long ctr = counter.getAndSet(0)
                                        println("I am done. Total event count is $ctr")
                                     } )
        .subscribe { println("Just received [$it] from the infinite stream ") }
```

This isn't very functional, but this kind of reporting tends to break normal streams.